No handler mapping for given request if @ComponentScan for controllers and @EnableWebMvc are separated in two configurationes classes
I've two configurations classes:
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig {
}

@Configuration
@ComponentScan("io.abned.spring.websocket.controllers")
public class AppConfig {
}

And a controller(in io.abned.spring.websocket.controllers) and its test class:

@RestController
@RequestMapping("api/v1")
public class HelloController {

    @GetMapping("hello")
    public String hello() {
        return "Hello, world!";
    }
}

@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextHierarchy({
        @ContextConfiguration(classes = AppConfig.class),
        @ContextConfiguration(classes = WebConfig.class)
})
class HelloControllerIntegrationTest {

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext wac;

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() {
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(wac).build();
    }

    @Test
    void testHello() throws Exception {
        mockMvc.perform(get("/api/v1/hello"))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$").value("Hello, world!"));
    }
}

This test failed. But if I move the @ComponentScan to WebConfig then it's succeded.
So, why it is failed if I separate @ComponentScan to @EnableWebMvc ?
PS: I use spring 6.1.10 (without spring boot)
SOLUTION
I must use DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration directly and override createRequestMappingHandlerMapping because RequestMappingHandlerMapping detects only bean in the current context by default (detectHandlerMethodsInAncestorContexts = false). So registered controllers in parent context does not detected.
@Configuration
public class WebConfig  extends DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration {
    @Override
    protected RequestMappingHandlerMapping createRequestMappingHandlerMapping() {
        RequestMappingHandlerMapping requestMapping = super.createRequestMappingHandlerMapping();
        requestMapping.setDetectHandlerMethodsInAncestorContexts(true);
        return requestMapping;
    }
}


can u show the root, config and controller packages ?

@RyuzakiL I've only one controller class on it. You can see in the code snipper the HelloController class.
